# RDS MySQL A B replicate across continents?

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, rds

I have a web app that I run for Australian customers hosted on AWS using RDS.

Can I bi-directional replicate in realtime the database to the USA and Europe AND expect to be able to have a single database shared between frontend servers connecting to their local MySQL target in each country?

Comment: Would a CDN serve your needs instead?

Comment: Thanks I use a CDN already. This is a web app that needs user details/data stored in a DB